# Automatically column width for all rows based on previous rows

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do a table like that:

[image]

or like that if option 1 was impossible:

[image]

My xml is like that and I'm using a ExpandableListView:

```
<TableLayout>
     <TableRow>
          <TextView/>
          <TextView/>
          <TextView/>
     </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I've tried width=0, layout_weight=1 as I saw in others questions but none seems to do what I need.

How can I do it?